# How to handle AdSense ads on an SPA - single page app?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, single-page-application

I have an SPA (single page app) that I'll display AdSense ads on it.

The main reason I've designed as an SPA, is because I do not want users to refresh the page in order to see different content. All routing is done client-side with Javascript. I'm using `React`, `Firebase` and `React-Router`.

But on AdSense docs, we have this:

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en

> **Auto-refreshing ads**
>
> Publishers are **not permitted to refresh a page or an element of a page without the user requesting a refresh.** This includes placing ads on pages or in placements that auto-redirect or auto-refresh. Additionally, publishers may not display the ads for a preset time (i.e., pre-roll) before users can view content such as videos, games, or downloads.

The fact is users will NEVER request a refresh on my app.

What is the proper way to show multiple ads on a single app?

**OPTION #1**

- Render a new app only when users change pages.

**Example:**

- Users "navigates" to: `/blog/some-blog-post-slug-A`  // SEE ADS
- Users "navigates" to: `/blog/some-blog-post-slug-B`  // SEE NEW ADS

Although the page is not technically refreshing, it's just like a page refresh, because the URL will change, but this is all done locally. I will re-render the blogPost component, based on the new URL route.

CAN I DO THIS? Render new ads based on a client-side route change?

And what if my app is a game, and users will spend like 30 minutes on a single screen, playing the game. Am I only allowed to show 1 single ad for the whole 30 minutes session? Or can I re-render it on a specific interval?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue, I am planning to add Adsense to React app,